# Dispatcher initialization failed error in Struts2 application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts2

I am getting the following errors

> SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed
>   Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/G:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/eventsense/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:12:45

I am using the following dependencies

```
struts2-core 2.3.15.1
struts2-dojo-plugin 2.3.15.1
struts2-json-plugin 2.3.15.1
lucene-core 4.3.0
lucene-analyzers-common 4.3.0
lemmatization 1.0
lucene-queryparser 4.3.0
mysql-connector-java 5.1.27
jersey-core 1.18
jersey-server 1.18
jersey-servlet 1.18
jersey-json 1.18
gson 2.2.4
json 20090211
junit 4.8.1
javax.servlet-api 3.0.1
commons-logging 1.1.1
mongo-java-driver 2.12.1
solr-solrj 4.10.2
commons-codec 1.9
```

Comment: ... So there's an error in your `struts.xml` around the line indicated. Without the complete stacktrace, or at least the important parts, and the portion of the `struts.xml` in question, not sure how you expect anyone to help.

Comment: You're missing xwork jar. Show full stacktrace, post your struts.xml.